# SSLHandshakeException while using Retrofit in android 4.0.1

Tags: android, ssl, retrofit

My Url is https so when I using Retrofit for android 6.0 device its working fine. But with device having android android 4.0.1 OS its giving

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x1b97f80: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
>   error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:658 0x40265522:0x00000000)

Library used Retrofit.

Used some approch like

```
ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS)
            .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_0)
            .cipherSuites(
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
            .allEnabledTlsVersions()
            .supportsTlsExtensions(false)
            .allEnabledCipherSuites()
            .build();
```

by add this in `Ok` `HttpClient`.
But still fails.
Have gone through various stackoverflow links, but now worked.
Please suggest some approach.
Thanks.